# jQuery mobile dynamically changing background in CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set the background image page, have tried multiple solutions, some work once and not again others flash the background and then it goes back to the default background.

Have tried.

```
    var ad_image = "url('images/background.png')";

    $("#adCard1").css("background",ad_image);

    $("#adCard1").css("background-image",ad_image);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#adCard1").css("background",ad_image);
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Check the image is loading or not? `imgages` can be `images` !

Comment: Thank you.  This was not from the actual code.  It was just an example.  Live code is ..... url('+data.image_location+');  Some times the background image comes up then disappears.  On the element inspector it shows the image reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

change it as

```
var ad_image = "url("+data.imageURL+")";
$("#adCard1").css("background-image",ad_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion it helped and I finally after a few days of trying everything possible I came up with the following:

```
`
    $(".ui-panel-wrapper").css("background",ad_image);
    $(".ui-panel-wrapper").css("backgroundRepeat", 'no-repeat');
    $(".ui-panel-wrapper").css("backgroundPosition", "0px 0px"); `
```